# Is it possible to extend an Entity model with common queries?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework-4

Say I have a set of `Sites` that have a collection of `Users`.  I find myself violating the DRY principal whenever I have to redefine a query to get, say, the last visited `User` for a given `site`.

For example, my query may look like this:

```
from site in Context.Sites
where site.ID == 99
select new {
  ID = site.ID,
  Name = site.Name,
  URL = site.URL,
  LastVisitedUser = site.Users.OrderByDescending(u => u.LastVisited).Select(u => new {
      ID = u.ID,
      Username = u.Username,
      Email = u.EmailAddress
   })
   .FirstOrDefault()
}
```

That query returns what I want, but I find myself repeating this same select for the LastVisitedUser in multiple places as I'm selecting the site in different ways to populate my various ViewModels.

So, I thought that I would simply extend my Site Entitiy class with a property like so:

```
public partial class Site {
  public LastVisitedUser {
    get {
      var query = from user in Users
                  where user.SiteID == this.ID
                  orderby user.LastVisited descending
                  select user;
      return query.FirstOrDefault()
    }
  }
}
```

In this manner, whenever I am selecting a site it would be fairly trivial to grab this property.  This *almost* works, however I am stuck trying to assign an Entity user into my UserViewModel property into the LastVisited property of my return, without an obvious way on how to project the `User` into my ViewModel version.

Perhaps an example would help explain.  What I'm trying to accomplish would be something like this:

```
from site in Context.Sites
where site.ID == 99
select new SiteViewModel {
  ID = site.ID,
  Name = site.Name,
  URL = site.URL,
  LastVisitedUser = site.LastVisitedUser <--- NOTE    
}
```

NOTE = This is my point of failure.  `LastVisitedUser` is a ViewModel with a subset of `User` data.

Am I going about this in the correct manner?  Can I achieve what I'm trying to do, or am I horribly misguided?  Am I about to sove this issue and run into others?

Thanks!

Comment: are these methods being called from your Controllers, or on which layer do you need these queries?

Comment: In my repository.  My Controllers are dealing with IEnumerable variants or concrete objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: The former answer was not correct. You cannot use extension method on the navigation property but you can still create extension method for the whole `Site` projection.

Just create simple reusable extension method:

```
public static IQueryalbe<SiteModel> GetSiteModels(this IQueryable<Site> query)
{
    return query.Select(site => new SiteModel {
                     ID = site.ID,
                     Name = site.Name,
                     URL = site.URL,
                     LastVisitedUser = site.Users
                                           .OrderByDescending(u => u.LastVisited)
                                           .Select(u => new LastVisitedUser {
                                                ID = u.ID,
                                                Username = u.Username,
                                                Email = u.EmailAddress
                                            }});
}
```

Now you should be able to use that extension in your former query:

```
Context.Sites.Where(site => site.ID == 99).GetSiteModels();
```

Your example will not work because your property is not visible for Linq-to-entities.

Comment: I've been trying this, and no matter what I do, I keep getting an error: EntityCollection<User> does not contain a definition for GetLastUsers() and no extension method accepting a first argument of type EntityCollection<User> could be found.  I've even placed the extension method within my repository class to ensure I'm not messing up a namespace or something.  Am I missing something?

Comment: You are right, it doesn't work because expression method cannot be used inside projection on navigation property. You must create extension method for the whole Site projection.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you what to reuse common queries with different extensions, you just nead to write some base query and get different results and some Where lambda expressions. If you profile it, you will see that you have just one query to DB just return IQuerable in a base query